# Traceroute Terminal vs Network Utility different?

Tags: macos, terminal, network

Why would a Terminal `traceroute #.#.#.#` show different results than using Network Utility.app? Here is the first 3 hops. I am connected to PIA VPN but regardless both methods should show the same results I would think.

Terminal

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  10.199.1.1 (10.199.1.1)  42.559 ms  39.696 ms  38.293 ms
2  * * *
3  184-75-211-129.amanah.com (184.75.211.129)  49.639 ms
162.219.176.225 (162.219.176.225)  56.780 ms
dpaall.webexpressmail.net (162.219.179.65)  69.798 ms
```

Network Utility.app

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
1  10.199.1.1 (10.199.1.1)  41.221 ms  38.355 ms  47.237 ms
2  vl685-c8-10-c6-1.pnj1.choopa.net (209.222.15.225)  41.262 ms  38.674 ms  41.912 ms
3  vl126-br1.pnj1.choopa.net (108.61.92.105)  44.092 ms  36.200 ms  40.407 ms
```

Comment: This is unusual, as I would expect the same system call to be used between them, but I can confirm that I too get different output between Network Utility app and `traceroute` run in Terminal on 10.7 Lion.

Comment: I also get different results which should not occur. When I do a trace route to 184.75.213.210 via the command line it does not resolve the end point.

Comment: I found a solution and posted it to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379249/4222

Answer (score 2):

IP traffic does not necessarily follow the same path. Leaving your system, each router will choose the path that it sees fit for **each** packet, and this path may change depending on availability/congestion. It won't care **how** they got there.

So in the case of traceroute that is sending ICMP packets they don't always necessarily follow the same path too, ICMP runs on top of IP.